# Using google charts api to show mutiple charts

Tags: jquery, google-visualization

I am using google charts api for my project. My project is simple get json from url and display chart.

I use something like this. it works fine

```
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "/files/data.json",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
```

the json data at "/files/data.json" looks like this

```
{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        .....
      ]
}
```

Actually I have three charts on the same page. I don't want to send three separate requests to retrieve data from the server. how can I nest the data for three charts in a json response. And **var data** would change **jsondata.nest1** right?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this :

```
{
 nest1: [
 {
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        .....
      ]
 },

 {
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        .....
      ]
 },

 {
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        .....
      ]
 }

 ]
}
```

Then you can access data with jsonData.nest1[0], jsonData.nest1[1] and jsonData.nest1[2].

One tip: to use a shortcut for ajax JSON, you can use getJSON http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Hope this helps,

Michael

Comment: Thanks Michael for your help. But It does not work. I get error as Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: The best idea would be to use the callback function of .getJSON(). See the documentation for examples of this!